# What is the difference between these two jsx syntax in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-functional-component

I have this form that draws some fields dynamically and set the state of the form, the code is working flawlessly check the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-star-8zwqm7?file=/src/components/Original.jsx),
this is how the return statement looks like

```
 return (
    <div className="patientForm">
      <section className="form">
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          {patientFormFields.map(({ title, type, values }, index) => (
            <div className="form-group w-50" key={index}>
              <label htmlFor={title}>{capitalize(title)}</label>
              {type === "select" ? (
                <select
                  name={title}
                  id={title}
                  value={formValue[title]}
                  onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, title)}
                >
                  {values.map(({ value, text }, index) => (
                    <option key={index} value={value}>
                      {text}
                    </option>
                  ))}
                </select>
              ) : (
                <input
                  type={type}
                  name={title}
                  id={title}
                  placeholder={capitalize(title)}
                  value={formValue[title]}
                  onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, title)}
                />
              )}
            </div>
          ))}
        </form>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
```

My problem is I don't like having my return statement be filled with logic so I tried to refactor the logic part into a separate component, check the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-star-8zwqm7?file=/src/components/RefactorOne.jsx),

this is my return statement now

```
return (
    <div className="patientForm">
      <section className="form">
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          {patientFormFields.map(({ title, type, values }, index) => (
            <div className="form-group w-50" key={index}>
              <label htmlFor={title}>{capitalize(title)}</label>
              <FormFields type={type} title={title} values={values} />
            </div>
          ))}
        </form>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
```

but it didn't work as expected, the input kept losing focus when I type, I looked up the problem and it seems that when I update my state, the component rerenders, react can't compare the two components/functions and that causes a creating a new component, I guess?! when I tried using a regular function (line-53) that returns JSX it worked correctly, check the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-star-8zwqm7?file=/src/components/RefactorTwo.jsx).

this is my return statement now

```
return (
    <div className="patientForm">
      <section className="form">
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          {patientFormFields.map(({ title, type, values }, index) => (
            <div className="form-group w-50" key={index}>
              <label htmlFor={title}>{capitalize(title)}</label>
              {FormFields(type, title, values)}
            </div>
          ))}
        </form>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The explanation sort of make sense but I don't understand why did my code work when I converted the JSX call in the component return to a regular function, aren't they both functions? and shouldn't my second code also be buggy since functions are reference type, and react shouldn't be able to compare them, I feel there is something missing that I don't understand. Also, what would be a better way to refactor that logic away from the component return?

edit: add code snippet to the problem

Comment: You should include at least the most crucial parts of the code int he question

Comment: You should not define a component inside another component, because then the inner component will be completely unmounted and then mounted again every time the parent component rerenders.

Comment: There is a difference between an element's tree and a component in react. Your second refactor returns an element's tree, the function is executed before it's returned. In the first refactor the component is executed after it's returned.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski It felt like a lot of code, I thought people might get lost as they would need to see the whole component

Comment: any resource where I can read about this topic in more depth @KonradLinkowski